# How do I configure the width of application launcher?

Tags: unity, configuration

Is it possible to configure the unity application launcher's width, so it will be smaller ?
How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 11.04 and upwards, you can do this from ccsm.

Open the Unity plugin options and choose the launcher size you would like from there:
[image: Screenshot]